# How to set skin to null for button?

Tags: apache-flex, skinning

How to set skin to null for button?

```
button = new Button();
button.useHandCursor=true;
button.buttonMode =true;
```

i want to set button.skin = null

Thanks

Comment: What is your intended use of a button with a null skin?  Seems to me you could just set visible and includeInLayout to false on the button and get the same result.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex 3 or Flex 4?

- Flex 4 version

  button.setStyle("skinClass", null)
- Flex 3 version

  button.setStyle("upSkin", null)
  button.setStyle("downSkin", null)
  button.setStyle("overSkin", null)
  button.setStyle("disabledSkin", null)

Comment: In Flex 4 / Spark Architecture if a skinnable component does not have a skin set--or has a null skin--it will produce a runtime error.  I get that all the time when I forget to set defaults.  I'm not sure why someone would want to do that.